# RSQLite db created on Mac OSX not inserting data on Windows

Tags: r, sqlite, rsqlite

I'm really stuck here.  I created a SQLite db on the Mac OSX, and now am trying to INSERT data into it on Windows. I'm doing it in R on both platforms, using the RSQLite library.

I'm trying to insert the data from data frame `x`:

```
> str(x)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Julian   : int ...
 $ Date     : chr ...
 $ Time     : chr ...
 $ ID       : chr ...
 $ Item     : chr ...
 $ Value    : num ...
 $ Payment  : chr ...
 $ Type     : chr ...
 $ Customer : chr ...
 $ Operator1: chr ...
 $ Operator2: chr ...
 $ Weekday  : int ...
```

I try the following steps and get the error message below:

```
> db=dbConnect(dbDriver("SQLite"),dbname=f)
> dbSendQuery(db,"INSERT INTO Entries VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",x)
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) :
  unused argument (list( ... ))
```

**UPDATE**: The suggestion below by vaettchen of using dbWriteTable with append=TRUE worked, thanks. However, there is still an issue with dbSendQuery, see error below when trying to remove all entries with id=74:

```
> dbSendQuery(db,"DELETE FROM Entries WHERE ID=?",id)
Error in .local(conn, statement, ...) : unused argument (74)
```

Appreciate any help, it might just be something stupid I can't see.  Many thanks.

Comment: Did you consider `dbWriteTable` with `append = TRUE`?

Comment: Great, this worked. But I still have an issue with dbSendQuery, I updated the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what works for me in such a situation:

```
id <- 74
sql <- paste( "DELETE FROM Entries WHERE ID=", id )
dbGetQuery( db, sql )
```

If you want to remove more than one id, use a loop:

```
id <- c( 73, 74, 78 )
for( i in id )
{
  sql <- paste( "DELETE FROM Entries WHERE ID=", i )
  dbGetQuery( db, sql )
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm only a casual RSQLite user and never used `dbSendQuery` directly. It may yield performance gains for large DBs or frequent bulk updates.